# FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The format of the phone number provided is incorrect

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I try to make an authentication in firebase using phone number. But unfortunately, all the time I get the same issue, in log: "com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The format of the phone number provided is incorrect. Please enter the phone number in a format that can be parsed into E.164 format. E.164 phone numbers are written in the format [+][country code][subscriber number including area code]. [ Invalid format. ]"
My dependencies in build.gradle(:app):

```
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.1.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.5
```

[This is my phone numbers for testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4hrO.png)

```
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        mCallBack = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks(){
            override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential : PhoneAuthCredential){
                AUTH.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener{task ->
                    if(task.isSuccessful){
                        showToast("Welcome")
                        (activity as RegisterActivity).replaceActivity(MainActivity())
                    }else
                        showToast(task.exception?.message.toString());
                }
            }
            @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
            override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException){
                showToast(e.message.toString())
                Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationFailed: $e") 
            }
            override fun onCodeSent(id: String, token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken){
                replaceFragment(EnterCodeFragment(mPhoneNumber, id))
            }
        }
////////
    }
    private fun authUser(){
        mPhoneNumber = mBinding.registerInputPhoneNumber.toString();
        val mPhoneNumberOptions = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder()
            .setPhoneNumber(mPhoneNumber)
            .setActivity(activity as RegisterActivity)
            .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setCallbacks(mCallBack)
            .build()
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(mPhoneNumberOptions)
    }
```

The format of my phone numbers is corrent, despite this, I tryed other format (without plus and etc). I tryed to use real phone number, I had ran the app on real android device - the result the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please, double check that you do not have any whitespaces/dashes in your phone number string. E164 format assumes that your phone number is written like this `+4915733366657`.
Some symbols might be invisible, so you can use debugger to make sure you do not have anything but digits and the leading `+` sign.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have found the problem, I used the debugger and find out that mPhoneNumber gets null. In this line must be:  mPhoneNumber = mBinding.registerInputPhoneNumber.text.toString();